# Paraview programmatically plot quantities over line, using only data on nodes

Tags: python, plot, paraview

I have a dataset on a 2D domain.
I mean to get an XY plot of data along a line which contains a number of element edges.
I would typically do this with PlotOverLine.

Now I want to obtain a similar plot, but with my data points located only at the actual locations of nodes in my mesh.
In this way, my XY plot (and its underlying data) would be directly representative of the mesh resolution in my original data.

**How can this be done programmatically, 1) from the UI as a macro, 2) from the UI at the python shell, 3) at the CLI (`pvpython myscript.py`)?**

I couldn't even find how to do this via GUI.
I started by *Select Points On*, but I couldn't go any further.
Moreover, if this is the right way to start, I wouldn't be able to transfer it to python code, since *Start Trace* does not include  *Select Points On* in the output trace, so I wouldn't know how to add it to code.

PS: This resembles the procedure in Abaqus whereby one defines a Path based on an arbitrary set of points (which can be nodes, e.g.) and then plots a given quantity along that path.

Comment: Selecting points manually and implementing a PlotOverSelection filter in a plugin should be doable.